# Facing this error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

facing this error while debugging this code in line "df = pd.read_csv(file)" . i am passing the folder path as input. How should i pass that folder path ??

```
def clean_files(input_folder_path,output_folder_path):
    #get the ist of all csv files in the given folder
    csv_list = [file for file in os.listdir(input_folder_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
    
    #initialize an empty list to store the individual dataframe
    df =[]
    
    #loop through each csv file, clean the first five rows and create a dataframe
    for file in csv_list:
        file_path = os.path.join(input_folder_path,file)
    #read the csv file into a dataframe
    for i, file in enumerate(csv_list):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
    #clean the first 5 rows
    df = df.iloc[5:]
    
    #append the cleaned dataframe to the list
    cleaned_df = df.append(df)
    
    #display the cleaned dataframes
    for i, df in enumerate(cleaned_df):
        print(f"df{i+1}:\n{df}\n")
    
    #save the cleaned dataframe to a new csv fil in the output folder
    output_folder_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"cleaned_{file}")
    df.to_csv(output_folder_path, index=False)
    
    #append the cleaned dataframe to the list
    cleaned_df.append(df)
    return cleaned_df
```

i am creating a code where i need to read all the csv files in a given folder, clean them all and then copy the cleaned csv to another folder path.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to pass the folder to `pd.read_csv`. I've changed your code to something like this.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def clean_files(input_folder_path, output_folder_path):
    #get the ist of all csv files in the given folder
    csv_list = [file for file in os.listdir(input_folder_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
    
    #initialize an empty list to store the individual dataframe
    df =[]
    
    #loop through each csv file, clean the first five rows and create a dataframe
    for file in csv_list:
        file_path = os.path.join(input_folder_path,file)
    #read the csv file into a dataframe
    for i, file in enumerate(csv_list):
        df = pd.read_csv(f"{input_folder_path}{file}") # I add a folder `input_folder_path` before the file so that the computer knows where file is.
    
    #clean the first 5 rows
    df = df.iloc[5:]
    
    #append the cleaned dataframe to the list
    cleaned_df = df.append(df)
    
    #display the cleaned dataframes
    for i, df in enumerate(cleaned_df):
        print(f"df{i+1}:\n{df}\n")
    
    #save the cleaned dataframe to a new csv fil in the output folder
    output_folder_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"cleaned_{file}")
    df.to_csv(output_folder_path, index=False)
    
    #append the cleaned dataframe to the list
    cleaned_df.append(df)
    return cleaned_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clean_files('./csv_files/', './')
```

By the way, your `file_path` variable is not used in the code.

Perhaps you wanted to pass `file_path` to `pd.read_csv()`, but you forgot.

Comment: i tried this; however, it throws error : Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError. So just changed to  df = pd.read_csv(f"{input_folder_path}/{file}") and then ran again  and getting error at step :  cleaned_df = pd.concat(df)

Comment: The key difference is that I have a `/` at the end of `input_folder_path`. And your code doesn't have a `/` at the end of `input_folder_path`.  Both coding styles are ok.